# Publishing customization doesn't publish customizations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Sometimes when I hit *Publish All Customizations*, I notice that the process doesn't result in the expected outcome. At first, I blamed my forgetfulness but finally, I took statistics. There **is** something wrong with the publishing facility. I even have a short screencast to prove it!

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely **not** doing anything wrong. I've see that behavior quite a few times. It started with RU11, I believe and it's a bug. It appears seldom and has (most often) to do with importing a solution from a lower version of a roll-up, as far I've cared to regard
it.

Just to make sure we're talking about the same phenomenon, see [my blog](http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/publishing-customizations-doesnt-take-effect-in-crm-on-line/) if you recognize the signs from the screenshots.

Short remedy - hit the button again. It always works the second time.
Long term solution - wait until Microsoft fixes it.